Acceder a los items de un DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
Al no existir en datagridview una propiedad selectedItem , no encuentro la forma de acceder a los Items. Hasta ahora era el usuario quien accedia al item y solamente capturaba ese valor, nunca me habia interesado como acceder a los valores de esa celda.
En el ejemplo, solo intento establecer el valor ( que ni eso ) pero lo que me interesa es acceder a los Item de esa celda.
 Dim nueva_columna As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    With nueva_columna
        .HeaderText = "Numeros"
        .Name = "Numeros"
        .Items.Add("0")
        .Items.Add("1")
        .Items.Add("2")
        .Items.Add("3")
    End With

  ...........
DataGridView_usuario.DataSource = data_usuario
DataGridView_usuario.Columns.Add(nueva_columna)

        For i = 0 To data_usuario.Rows.Count - 1

            DataGridView_usuario.Rows(i).Cells("numeros").Value = DataGridView_seleccion.Rows(i).Cells("permisos").Value.ToString
'Aqui me gustaria acceder a  DataGridView_usuario.Rows(i).Cells("numeros").Items 
     
        Next

